# Ember Array update - Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do I update an Ember Array in such a way that the change in the array also causes a change in the view?

Here's some pseudo code -

```
cacheArr: Em.A([]),
count: 1,
updateFxn: function() {
    this.incrementProperty(count);
    devObj = Ember.object.create();
    Ember.set(devObj,"ts", this.count);
    this.cacheArr.replace(0,1, [devObj]);
},


App.ArrayComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  refresh: function() {
    return cacheArr;
  }.property('localModel.length')
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/new-comp">
      {{#each item in refresh}}
         {{item.ts}}
      {{/each}}
</script>
```

I'm mystified to as why I'm getting the exception Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined ? I've searched for an answer, in vain. Appreciate insights.

Comment: what is devObj?  it looks like a global variable, and you're replacing whatever the first item from that array with that global object.  And how does that relate with the component?  it's difficult to understand even what you're talking about with your "pseudo" code

Comment: devObj is not a global variable. It is an Ember object that is created in updateFxn. I've updated the question accordingly. The gist is to update items in the array at different indexes, with devObj at different points of time. The component would pass this array to the template, for an updated view. Thus, having the UI update, when the array objects update. Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: that's still global defined like that, but it's all good. I'll create an example that should hopefully help you, I'm not sure if I still completely understand the replacing of the first item all the time, but maybe that's just something unrelated.  I also am not sure if that component makes sense, since it doesn't match the template name

Answer (score 1):

Ember watches things and updates them if you use the correct methods (get/set etc).  For arrays you'll want to use similar setters/getters (pushObject/removeObject/replace/objectAt etc).

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  cacheArr: Em.A([]),
  count: 1,
  actions:{
    updateFxn: function(item) {
      this.incrementProperty('count');
      var newColor = {
        color:'newColor', 
        count:this.get('count')
      };
      var index = this.indexOf(item);
      this.replace(index, 1, [newColor]);
    }
  }
});
```

As such, when you create computed properties, you generally want them watching items that can change the results of the computed property.  Let's dissect the following computed property.

```
refresh: function() {
  return cacheArr;
}.property('localModel.length')
```

Let's build up an example:

```
// let's grab refresh
var refresh = this.get('refresh');

console.log(refresh);

// let's change localModel which would make refresh dirty

this.get('localModel').pushObject({foo:'bar'});

var refresh2 = this.get('refresh');
```

at this point both `refresh` and `refresh2` would be the exact same, since the computed property always returns `cacheArr` (some global property);

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jisegaca/1/edit